# returning the correct item from a dictionary in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I'm only just learning Python, and as a fun exercise a friend asked me to write a program that: takes a random keyword from a separate file, compare the selected word to keywords in a dictionary, and prints a string that contains the keyword and the information attached to it (we'll call it the 'definition'). It is supposed to take a word, turn it into a euphemism byt adding the word Cincinnati in front of it, and then give the definition. The code I wrote is as follows.

```
    import random

    def cincinnati_word():
        list = open("cincinnati_stuff.txt").read().splitlines()
        word = random.choice(list)
        return word

    cincinnati_dict = {
        'car wash': 'you slip and slide through the legs of at least three hookers while they pee on you',
        'sweat sock': 'you get your whole foot into an orifice on someone else\'s body. Gettin\' in above the ankle makes it a tube sock',
        'hot pocket': 'you stick a lit firecracker into someone\'s pocket',
        'rest home': 'they make the dog chow',
        'Eggo waffle': 'you\'re having sex with someone and you press a tennis racket over his/her face and scream "Leggo my Eggo!"',
        'slip \'n slide': 'a kid throws up in the hallway at school',
        'dust mop': 'you don\'t trim your pubic hair at all',
        'prom date': 'a hooker agrees to the barter system of payment',
        'double dip': 'you get two VD\'s from the same partner at the same time',
        'dog park': 'the PETA shelter throws all the carcasses of the dogs they put down',
        'soda stream': 'you fart into someone\'s drink through a straw',
        'gramophone': 'someone blows a trumpet real loud in your ear',
        'tail pipe': 'you put a gerbil up your butt with a paper towel roll',

    }


    for word, meaning in cincinnati_dict.items():
        word = cincinnati_word()
        new_word = cincinnati_dict.get(word)
        if new_word:
            print "The Cincinnati Kid: \"The old Cincinnati %s, yeah, that's where %s.\"" % (word, meaning)
            break
        else:
            print "The Cincinnati Kid: \"The Cincinnat %s? That ain't no thing I ever hoid of." %(word)
        break
```

The part that's giving me trouble is that this code works... almost. It successfully retrieves a keyword from the text file. It successfully compares it to the list of keys in the dictionary. It also successfully returns a definition from the dictionary. The problem is that the definition returned is always the same one, regardless of which keyword is used. In every test I've run so far it always returns the definition for a Cincinnati gramophone.

I'm sure the answer is something stupidly obvious, but I've been staring at this for a couple of days and I can't see what would be causing this. Can anyone offer advice? I offer thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a loop (`for word, meaning in cincinnati_dict:`) when you don't need to. The unconditional `break` is a hint you don't want a loop at all.

Instead, just use `meaning` instead of `new_word` in the `get` call and the `if` condition:

```
word = cincinnati_word() 
meaning = cincinnati_dict.get(word)
if meaning:
    print "The Cincinnati Kid: \"The old Cincinnati %s, yeah, that's where %s.\"" % (word, meaning)
else:
    print "The Cincinnati Kid: \"The Cincinnati %s? That ain't no thing I ever hoid of." %(word)
```

Comment: Wow, that fixed it right up. Thanks. I'm still curious about why the loop kept picking one meaning though.

Comment: You'd only iterate once (since you'd always hit a `break`), so the one meaning was whatever came first from `items`.